# My image won't show up

Tags: html

Here's the code, what am I missing? The img folder is on my desktop and it contains the cupcake image. The path look good, but it just won't show.

Help please!!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Sample</title>

</head>

<body>
<img src = "img/cupcake.jpg"/>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the html page located? When you use relative paths such as `img/cupcake.jpg` there must be an `img` folder at the same location as your html page.

Comment: What is the server response for the image request?  You can see requests and responses in browser debugging tools.  Does the image file exist?  Does the web server have access to it?

Comment: Are you sure the image file exist, has the right permissions and your webserver can serve it?

Comment: the img folder might be on your desktop, but where's this .html file? It has to be on the desktop as well... And are you loading this page via an `http://...` url? or `file:///`?

Comment: No the img folder wasn't located in the html location - silly me, thanks guys. I've done this before, but was just refreshing myself after a few months break and it appears I've forgotten a lot!

Comment: Another issue which might cause this problem (for someone else), is if the path and the image file are not in the same case. e.g. the image is actually cupcake.JPG and  the reference is to cupcake.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `img` directory needs to be *on the same level as the HTML page you're viewing*. It doesn't matter if it's "on the desktop".

Move the image into a folder `img` which is found on the same folder as the `.html` file.

Comment: It's all sorted now - thanks so much for your immediate response...it really is a great community here :)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark (✔) under the answer's score.